# The appearance of the admin panel in Django is broken

Tags: python, django

I am a Django beginner. When I enter the address of the admin panel, I encounter a broken and strange panel:
https://s6.uupload.ir/files/screenshot_2023-09-02_155801_0mvm.png

Comment: try `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: I tried ```python manage.py collectstatic``` but it didn't work.